# Trace32 continuously read file

Tags: scripting, embedded, trace32, lauterbach

I'm trying to make a script for Trace32 PRACTICE language that reads some data from a .txt file and then passes the values to a variable that I need to debug.

My problem is that I cannot make it return to the top of the file and start over, once the .txt reaches the end. Any ideas ?

Here is what I have at the moment and it enters the IF from the start :

```
OPEN #1 C:/Sandboxes/JLR_ADAS_DC/Trace32Scripts/ListCam_new.txt /Read

PRIVATE &value                // declare macro

WHILE TRUE() 
(
    if FILE.EOFLASTREAD()
    (
        CLOSE #1

        OPEN #1 C:/Sandboxes/JLR_ADAS_DC/Trace32Scripts/ListCam_new.txt /Read
    )
    else
    (
        READ #1 %LINE &line

        &value=STRing.TRIM(STRing.SPLIT("&line",",",0))

        PRINT "&value"

        V canConfigInitFlag = &value
    )
)

CLOSE #1

ENDDO
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Closing and re-opening the file to return to the top of the file is the correct approach. (There is no seek-command.)

However there is a bug in your script:
The function `FILE.EOFLASTREAD()` returns TRUE() if the last `READ` command did only return empty data because you've reached the end of the file. In your code you do no longer execute the `READ` command once you've reached the end of the file. Thus `FILE.EOFLASTREAD()` will continue to return TRUE().

The following will work:

```
OPEN #1 C:/Sandboxes/JLR_ADAS_DC/Trace32Scripts/ListCam_new.txt /Read
PRIVATE &value &line  // declare macros

WHILE TRUE() 
(
    READ #1 %LINE &line
    IF FILE.EOFLASTREAD()  // Last READ was after the end of the file
    (
        CLOSE #1
        OPEN #1 C:/Sandboxes/JLR_ADAS_DC/Trace32Scripts/ListCam_new.txt /Read
        READ #1 %LINE &line  // Read 1st line
    )
    &value=STRing.TRIM(STRing.SPLIT("&line",",",0))
    PRINT "&value"
    Var.set canConfigInitFlag=&value
)
CLOSE #1
ENDDO
```